# git-svn dcommit fails because the repository name contains a space

Tags: git, svn, spaces, dcommit

When attemping to `git svn dcommit` to a repository that has spaces in it's name, I get the following error:

```
Committing to http://svn.kuluvalley.com/Meet the Expert/trunk ...
http://svn.kuluvalley.com/Meet the Expert/trunk
Filesystem has no item: '/!svn/bc/7397/Meet' path not found at /usr/libexec/git-core/git svn line 592
```

It looks like `git svn` doesn't support directories with spaces in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-svn clone fails "fatal: Not a valid object name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365317/git-svn-clone-fails-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the problem with spaces is fixed in Git >= 1.8.0 (See: [#786942](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/786942)).

So you should consider to upgrade it.

See GitHub Home page: https://github.com/git/git

Answer (score 7):

I was able to work around the problem of `git svn` not working for repositories with spaces in them by patching git-svn.

I updated the `url_path` function to:

```
sub url_path { 
  my ($self, $path) = @_; 

  my $url = $self->{url} . '/' . $self->repo_path($path); 
  if ($self->{url} =~ m#^https?://#) { 
    $url =~ s!([^~a-zA-Z0-9_./-])!uc sprintf("%%%02x",ord($1))!eg; 
    $url =~ s!^(https?)%3A//!$1://!; 
  } 
  $url 
}
```

For windows (x64) users, this function can be found in Editor.pm file, which is  located in

> {Git installation folder}\mingw64\share\perl5\site_perl\Git\SVN\

This ensures that the spaces in the url are encoded correctly.

It seems to work for me, but hasn't been tested thoroughly.