# git-svn clone fails "fatal: Not a valid object name"

Tags: git-svn

Whilst doing `git svn clone -s https://svn.example.com/repo/` I received the following output:

```
r3073 = a6132f3a937b632015e66d694250da9f606b8333 (refs/remotes/trunk)
Found possible branch point: https://svn.example.com/repo/trunk => https://svn.example.com/repo/branches/v1.3, 3073
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: repo/branches/trunk
    real path: repo/trunk
Continuing ahead with repo/trunk
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: repo/branches/trunk
    real path: repo/trunk
Continuing ahead with repo/trunk
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: repo/branches/trunk
    real path: repo/trunk
Continuing ahead with repo/trunk
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/trunk):
expected path: repo/branches/trunk
    real path: repo/trunk
Continuing ahead with repo/trunk
fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/tags/Sync Controllers
cat-file commit refs/remotes/tags/Sync Controllers: command returned error: 128
```

Running `git branch -a` gives:

```
remotes/tags/Sync%20Controllers
remotes/tags/v1.1
remotes/trunk
remotes/v1.2
```

I think the problem is that "remotes/tags/Sync Controllers" != "remotes/tags/Sync%20Controllers".

Comment: See as well:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/786942

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584605/git-svn-dcommit-fails-because-the-repository-name-contains-a-space There is patch available there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The tag on SVN has a space in it, but the tag in git had this space converted to `%20` (URL encoded). To solve it just manually add a new tag with the verbatim name:

```
cd .git/refs/remotes/tags/
mv Sync%20Controllers Sync\ Controllers
```

Then run the `git svn clone` command again.

*(Normally you'd do this with `git tag OLDTAG NEWTAG` but git was not allowing me to define a tag with a space in. The tag files are simply text files containing the hash of the relevant commit.)*

Comment: I tried that solution however, I get the following error:
`fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/tags/WITH SPACE'`. How to solve that?

Comment: (I'm using git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0)

Comment: This worked for me with a tag with a `~` character in the file name as well. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to workaround it in case of branches? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477630/migrating-svn-to-git-branches-with-white-space-in-the-names

Comment: Probably the same but `cd .git/refs/heads/` or `cd .git/logs/refs/heads/` instead

Comment: I also tried renaming but, like D.R. above, I obtain the error `fatal: Reference has invalid format`. I am using GIT 1.8.3.1 and SVN 1.8.11

Comment: I ran in a simular problem, but when i tried to rename the conflicting file, it didn't  exist in the path, in my case being refs/remotes/origin/CONFLICTING_FILE. My solution was to rename the entry corresponding to the CONFLICTING_FILE in the .git/packged-refs, removing the offending characters.

Comment: upadating .git/packged-refs and replacing all the %20 with spaces fixed it for me... git 2.18.0

Comment: @MSillence Life saver. Ran into this today after a network timeout failure after running git svn clone for 24hrs. Modifying .git/packaged-refs and removing %20 allowed it all to continue where it left off.

Answer (score 5):

You may use git-svn server-side alternative, [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) in order to avoid many of git-svn translation problems.

I'm a SubGit developer and could say that we worked a lot to resolve character translation issues like the one above; in this particular case tag would be translated to a `refs/tags/Sync+Controllers` tag.

Note also, that git-svn has translated Subversion tag as a branch instead of a tag.

Comment: Do I have to install SubGit on the server or it's not necessary? What if I don't have admin access to my svn repo?

Comment: With SubGit 2.0 you do not have to have an admin access to your repository. You would need to enable pre-revprop-change hook to get a full featured authors mapping, but chances are that it is already enabled. Check http://subgit.com/eap/ for more details.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue today, and considered this branch which contains a pace in it is not important, i just run

```
git branch -r -d partialPayment%202.4
```

And re-run `git` svn fetch
It skipped current branch and continue grabbing the next one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using git 1.29.2 and getting the issue too. Additionlly it is running into a Windows Server 2016 and git is under cygwin.

Was checking into `/GitMigration/.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin`, and the folder is there with blank spaces not `%20` so nothing to change on it.

However into the `packed-refs` the tag that is producing the problem does not appears, no name and no hash.

The problem should has another related issue with something else that produce the error, not just this.

Looking into the `./.git/config` found a series of repetitions of the following lines:

```
branches = server/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
tags = server/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

That are producing each time i did run the git-svn clone sentence. So i did remove those from the config file, save it and run again, but this time using `git svn fetch`, to prevent get again the lines duplicated, and voala !! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with spaces is fixed in Git >= 1.8.0 (See: [#786942](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/786942)).

So you should upgrade it.

I've tested it and it seems to work in the recent version of git.

See GitHub Home page: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: I am using 1.8.5.2 and ran into this problem

Comment: And do you think it's related to the spaces or some special characters in your branch/tag names, etc.?

Comment: I have seen this problem too with git = 1.8.3.1, svn = 1.7.14 and svn2git = 2.3.2
Related to spaces in SVN branch names.

Comment: i have git version 2.23.0 and just got this problem