# Converting a subversion repository to git, why am I seeing "fatal: not a valid object name"?

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn

I am seeing the following output while converting a subversion repo to git.

```
> Found possible branch point: <repo-url>/trunk => <repo-url>/branches/CMT_PHASE3, 18441
> fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/BlueSimViewer 5.0 20110316 Branch
> cat-file commit refs/remotes/BlueSimViewer 5.0 20110316 Branch: command returned error: 128
```

The command I am running to convert the repo is

```
> git svn clone <repo-url> -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout converted-git > svnlog
```

This process has already converted 117 branches, some with spaces in their names. I first found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365317/git-svn-clone-fails-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name), which helped me move forward from a previous issue solved by git 1.8.x.x.

Any insight as to the cause of this problem and possible ways of fixing it are greatly appreciated.

I am running git version 1.8.1.1 on an Ubuntu 12.10 server. I am happy
to provide any other information that would be helpful.

Comment: Are there really spaces in the branch name?

Comment: Actually, I double checked the server and the closest branch name I can find is: BlueSimViewer5.0_20110316_Branch.

Comment: You can try SubGit for conversion, it has its own conversion engine, so, I think, you won't encounter such an error.

Comment: I notice that you have subgit.com in your profile. I appreciate honest attempts to resolve the question I asked, but your response adds nothing in the way of solving the problem I encountered. As far as I can tell, SubGit is a closed source tool that allows people to continue running Subversion. We are entirely moving away from that VCS, which makes SubGit a project that does not serve my needs.

Comment: @Stefan: I should mention that some branches did actually have spaces in their names (ie: Date Patch).

Comment: @XBigTK13X Currently the most of the SVN->Git conversion tools (like svn2git or git-svn bridge) run git-svn as the conversion engine, so if you don't find any solution to make git-svn work or it takes too much efforts, you can try the tool I proposed (yes, it's closed source but free for just conversion purposes, i.e. you case). If the information is not helpful, I can delete my comment.

Answer (score 8):

Might be too late now but I guess I found a, at least, odd solution.

Open the file `git-repo-name/.git/packged-refs` that you mentioned and replace the `%20` for spaces, save the document and try again. Worked for me.

Edited in Notepad++ with UTF-8.

Git version: `git version 2.6.2.windows.1` (win 7 64x via git bash).

Comment: It seems to work. I followed this procedure for a 9 year old SVN-repository which I just converted. I had to run git svn clone around 10 times to catch all instances of %20 in tag names.

Comment: A secondary observation is that after I ran this for the first time I got a series of "ignoring ref with broken name" warnings in the log from the process. I wiped the clone and ran it once more, upon which I did not get the named warnings.

I just did the conversion, so I'm not confident that the clone is 100% OK yet, but it seems correct, as far as I can see now.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, but I am not satisfied with the result. If someone can provide a way to do this without ignoring the problematic branches, then I am happy to accept his or her answer.

For each branch/tag that throws this error, open the following file

```
git-repo-name/.git/packged-refs
```

and place a pound symbol (#) at the start of the line containing the offending branch/tag.

For example, with respect to my question

```
b88c4df0d47a9ca43c2d0ffd4a1f6e471f98aebc refs/remotes/BlueSimViewer%205.0%2020110316%20Branch
```

becomes

```
#b88c4df0d47a9ca43c2d0ffd4a1f6e471f98aebc refs/remotes/BlueSimViewer%205.0%2020110316%20Branch
```

This marks the line as a comment, and git will continue the conversion process while ignoring the problematic branch.

I am still converting at the time of writing this answer. Although this solution means some branches are missed, at least I will know what branches aren't there.