# git svn clone: fatal: Reference has invalid format

Tags: git-svn

I'm using git svn clone to convert an svn repo to git and am facing issues with that. My first issue was -

```
fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/Customer Assistance
cat-file commit refs/remotes/Customer Assistance: command returned error: 128
```

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365317/git-svn-clone-fails-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name) but now it gives me the following error -

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/Customer Assistance'
for-each-ref --format=%(refname) refs/: command returned error: 128
```

PS: I'm doing this on a Windows machine and I'm using git 1.8.3.

Comment: I have the same problem, it also says here: "fatal: refs/remotes/trunk: not a valid SHA1"