# Git-svn clone error: "fatal: Not a valid object name 'refs/remotes/tags/Tag With Spaces'"

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using `git svn clone` (git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0) to migrate a Subversion repository to Git.

The Subversion repository has tags with spaces in it, which leads to `fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/tags/Tag With Spaces` errors.

According to various internet sources, this problem should have been fixed since Git 1.8.0, why am I still experiencing this? I also tried the marked answer from [git-svn clone fails "fatal: Not a valid object name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365317/git-svn-clone-fails-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name) which does not work either, it just changes the error to: `fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/tags/Tag With Spaces'`.

Anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm using svn2git now, which has no problem overcoming this issue (also does URL encoding of the branch labels, however, does not run into an error afterwards). Would still be interested in why `git svn clone` itself cannot handle the situation though.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. svn2git isn't an option though as I only wanted to use a local git repository in front of our svn server. A solution would thus be very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. We never investigated the issue further as svn2git worked for us. Hopefully somebody else has an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version [of svn2git](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git) (as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184869/6309)) has worked for the OP.

The other option, for a one-time import, is to use [SubGit](https://subgit.com/), which can also accommodate various tag names, including with spaces.