# SVN to Git Migration: additional commits found in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-svn

I had a repository in SVN, which i moved to Git using the "Git SVN Clone" command.

After Migrating repository, when checking the history of some of the files, we could see additional commits.

For example, lets say I have a file File.txt in SVN with 3 commits (lets say commit ids are r4, r5 and r6). After the migration, history of File.txt in GitLab shows more commits i.e (2dcdb6 corresponds r4, 5fgefd3 corresponds r5, 6sdsdr2 corresponds r6 and also 3jdhes5 corresponds r1, 1sdfer4 corresponds r2)

In r1 and r2, File.txt is not modified. When opening the commits 3jdhes5 and 1sdfer4 in GitLab it does not show the File.txt changes => which is expected.

But the History of File.txt is displaying the commits 3jdhes5 and 1sdfer4.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if a local `git log -- File.txt` also shows those same commits.

Try a new SVN export/import, using [`svn2git` mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184869/6309), and see if that new cloned Git repository exhibits the same "extra" history for `File.txt`.

If not, force push it to your GitLab repository, and check the `File.txt` history is coherent there as well.