# Migrating SVN (to Git) branches with white space in the names

Tags: git, svn, migration, branch

I'm facing a common problem migrating SVN to Git, basically I have some branches (on SVN) named with white spaces. Is there a way to solve or workaround it?

I've found some "solutions" but none of them worked for me.

- For tags with white spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365319/575643
- User svn2git do not worked also
- `git gc` just compress the data (basically)

I have a rude and massive repository to migrate and the command already migrated more then 90% of them (it took more then a week).

Someone has a clue how to solve it?

Git error:
`command returned error: 128`

System Info:

> Win 7 64x
>
> git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but 1.9.5 is far from being current. Latest release is 2.6.2, get it from here: https://git-scm.com/download

Comment: How are you migrating? `git svn clone`? `svn2git`? Which issues do you experience?

Comment: What's your SVN version? [https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/309062/answers/3039270 These guys] mention that `svn2git` had an issue with SVN < 1.7.9 and upgrading to 1.7.9 fixed it

Comment: @eckes I updated to `git version 2.6.2.windows.1` now, I will check. About the command, is that one: `git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt https://my.svn.repo local-repo-folder`

Comment: @eckes I have seen this problem too with svn = 1.7.14, git = 1.8.3.1 and svn2git = 2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file `git-repo-name/.git/packed-refs` and replace the `%20` for spaces.

Git version: `git version 2.6.2.windows.1` (win 7 64x via git bash).

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix things, exactly; git spits "warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/remotes/svn/xxx"; so it seems the branches with spaces in space are just ignored since this is invalid in git.

Comment: now working for me, I tried doint exactly that, replaced %20 with space but still having same issue on Windows GitBash

Comment: @pixel thanks for the feedback, consider upvote if this question/answer helped you :) cheers

Answer (score -1):

For anyone reading this now, and using say an Ubuntu box, which might affect behavior, using the svn2git tool, use both double quotes around the full URL and %20 in place of the spaces. This has worked for me now on a rather large conversion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).